# echo item according to session result quantity

Tags: php, echo

I want to fetch and echo item from MySQL database multi-times according to session quantity.

Example :

```
    id  | qty | item

    1  |   2  | shoe

    2  |   4  | net

    3  |   3  | phone
```

My result set should be like this :

```
shoe, shoe
net, net, net, net
phone, phone, phone
```

I tried :

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $each_item){ 
      $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
     $qty = $each_item['quantity'];
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' ORDER BY id");
      $qty = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
      $qty[] = $row;
    }foreach($qty as $row){
       $product_name = $row["product_name"];
      }
echo'$product_name';
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $each_item){ 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $qty = $each_item['quantity'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' 
               ORDER BY id");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $qty = $row['qty'];
            for($i=0; $i < $qty; $i++){
                echo $row['item'].' ';      
            }//end for
            echo '<br>';//go to next-line     
        }//end while
}//end foreach
```

Comment: $qty is a session result not a database result and it has no culumn in database should it like this?
<?php
session_start();
include "mysql.php";
?>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)
{
echo "shopping is empty";
}
else
{
foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
$item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
$qty = $each_item['quantity'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id'
ORDER BY id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for($i=0; $i < $qty; $i++){
$y = $row['product_name'];
}
echo '$y';
}
}
}
?>